# Copy/Paste in emacs ansi-term shell

Tags: shell, emacs

I have configured my emacs to run zsh shell within ansi-term. However, copy/paste no longer works i.e. nothing is getting pasted from kill-ring to the terminal. 
Changing the TERM to vt100, or eterm doesn't solve the problem.

Would appreciate any ideas or solution.

To provide context I have configured ansi-term as follows:

```lisp
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-a" '(lambda ()(interactive)(ansi-term "/bin/zsh")))
(global-set-key "\C-x\ a" '(lambda ()(interactive)(ansi-term "/bin/zsh")))
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You may want to simply switch between character mode and line mode while using the terminal. <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-j</kbd> will run `term-line-mode`, which treats the terminal buffer more like a normal text-buffer in which you can move the cursor and yank text. You can switch back to character mode by running `term-char-mode` with <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-k</kbd>.

Comment: This doesn't work too well with the right aligned prompt that things like zsh provide.

Comment: In Emacs 24, it appears that while in the terminal you need to press 'C-c C-j' to get to line mode, and then to get back, it is 'C-c C-k' as above.

Answer (score 20):

As described in [this lovely blog snippet](http://oremacs.com/2015/01/01/three-ansi-term-tips/), there's a function, `term-paste`, in `term.el`, that does exactly what you want.  By default the function is bound to `S-insert`, but it can be remapped to a more ergonomic `C-c y` by adding the following snippet to your init file:

```
(eval-after-load "term"
  '(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-c y") 'term-paste))
```

or with `use-package`

```
(use-package term
  :bind (:map term-raw-map ("C-c y" . term-paste)))
```

Note: [Sequences consisting of `C-c` and a letter are reserved for users](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html), so they can safely be used for custom key bindings.

Answer (score 5):

`ansi-term`, in `char-mode`, takes the ordinary bindings for the terminal emulation.  You need a new binding, plus a way to output to `ansi-term` correctly.  I use this:

```
(defun ash-term-hooks ()
  ;; dabbrev-expand in term
  (define-key term-raw-escape-map "/"
    (lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (let ((beg (point)))
        (dabbrev-expand nil)
        (kill-region beg (point)))
      (term-send-raw-string (substring-no-properties (current-kill 0)))))
  ;; yank in term (bound to C-c C-y)
  (define-key term-raw-escape-map "\C-y"
    (lambda ()
       (interactive)
       (term-send-raw-string (current-kill 0)))))
  (add-hook 'term-mode-hook 'ash-term-hooks)
```

When you do this, C-c C-y will yank.  It only does one yank, though, and you can't cycle through your kill-buffer.  It's possible to do this, but I haven't implemented it yet.

Comment: Appreciate your response. A ")" was missing in the end. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for me. I am getting error  C-c C-y  is undefined.

Comment: Hm, I tried running "emacs -q" with emacs 23.2, and (after fixing the missing paren you pointed out), I evaluated, copied some random text, then started ansi-term.  Pressing C-c C-y did in fact paste it.

Since this is using a hook, make sure you have restarted ansi-term after you evaluate it.  if that doesn't work, try it on an emacs started with -q.

You can also try pressing C-c C-h, which list bindings starting with C-c.  C-c C-y should be listed with ?? (?? because we're using an unnamed lambda).

Comment: Hello. I tried restarting emacs both with and without -q. But it is still not working. I am using emacs 23.1 on ubuntu. R C-c C-h  does not show any bindings when I start emacs normally. With -q I have several bindings but none about C-c C-y. Is there  a log or debug output that I can look into to see whats missing. 
Thanks. 
-Sandeep

Comment: With emacs 24 the code works but you need to use `C-x C-y` or `C-x C-/`

Comment: Anyone know how to get this working without a prefix? I would like to rebind s-v (super = mac command key).

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions work well for copying text from some buffer to ansi-term, but they aren't able to copy text from ansi-term to another buffer (eg copy a command you just ran to a shell script you're editing). Adding this to my .emacs file solved that problem for me (in Emacs 24.4):

```el
(defun my-term-mode-hook ()
  (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-y") 'term-paste)
  (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-k")
    (lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (term-send-raw-string "\C-k")
      (kill-line))))
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook 'my-term-mode-hook)
```

Note that if you want to bind kill/yank to a keystroke that starts with the ansi-term escape characters (by default C-c and C-x), and want this to work in the unlikely event that those change, you can instead define your keystrokes (without the leading escape) to `term-raw-escape-map`, as is done in user347585's answer.

Answer (score 0):

These other solutions don't work well for me, switching between character mode and line mode causes ansi-term to stop working properly randomly, and setting ansi-term's term-paste to C-c C-y (based on Glyph's link), didn't work the code snippet was for term, not ansi-term:

```
    (eval-after-load "ansi-term"
    '(define-key ansi-term-raw-map (kbd "C-c C-y") 'term-paste))
```

Answer (score 0):

I enabled `xterm-mouse-mode`, after that I was able to select text using mouse and copy using standard Mac command C button in `ansi-term` in emacs GUI in Mac OS X,